# React native-env file could not be found within the project

Tags: reactjs, environment-variables, native

```
Unable to resolve module @env from D:\react\weatho\weatho-app\App.js: @env could not be found within the project
```

`10:import {REACT_APP_WEATHER_API_KEY} from "@env";`

my env file looks like this:

`REACT_APP_WEATHER_API_KEY=2607fb610e6f9fecd16c84408d0b42a2`

and my Babel file looks like this:

```
  module.exports = function(api) {
        api.cache(true);
        return {
        plugin: ['babel-preset-expo','module:react-native-dotenv'],
     }
   }
```

and my env file is in root folder along with Appjson and few other files

Answer (score 4):

You should add a plugin like this(.env file must be in the root directory)

```
module.exports = function (api) {
api.cache(true);
return {
presets: ["babel-preset-expo"],
plugins: [
  [
    "module:react-native-dotenv",
    {
      moduleName: "@env",
      path: ".env",
    },
  ],
],
};
};
```

And don't forget to restart the expo start and ios/android restart the app.

If you are still getting the same issue then it can be a cache issue.

You can easily clear the babel cache by running the following command :

```
rm -rf node_modules/.cache/babel-loader/*
```

or

```
yarn start --reset-cache
```

or

```
expo r -c
```

Answer (score 2):

Your babel config has 'plugin' which should be 'plugins'

Answer (score 1):

very good way to fix this is to replace the "@env" with "react-native-dotenv" after moduleName like so : `plugins:[ [ "module:react-native-dotenv", { moduleName:"react-native-dotenv", path:".env", }, ] ]`
and when you're done implement it in your screen example : `import { API_KEY } from "react-native-dotenv";`

Answer (score 0):

```
yarn start --reset-cache
npm start -- --reset-cache
expo start -c
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following changes to babel.config.js file and it should work fine:

```js
module.exports = function (api) {
  api.cache(true);
  return {
    presets: ["babel-preset-expo"],
    plugins: [
      [
        "module:react-native-dotenv",
        {
          moduleName: "@env",
          path: ".env",
        },
      ],
    ],
  };
};
```

Make sure you restart the app a couple of times to see the changes. The .env file needs to be in the root directory.